# How to delete a character in a string using TCL

Tags: tcl

I have the following string

> "TCL is known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool
>   command language", TCL is known as "tool command language""

from the above input I want a output like below

> "TCL is known as tool command language, TCL is known as tool command
>   language, TCL is known as tool command language"

i.e. `only first and last double quotes should be displayed on output, and all other should be deleted,` Could someone let me know the different methods to accomplish this

Answer (score 4):

There can be many ways. I have tried with `regsub`

```
set str {"TCL is known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool command language""}
puts "Input : $str"
regsub -all {(.)"} $str {\1} output
puts "Output : $output"
```

which will produce the following

```
Input : "TCL is known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool command language""
Output : "TCL is known as tool command language, TCL is known as tool command language, TCL is known as tool command language"
```

The pattern I have used is `(.)"`. In regular expressions, the atom `.` will match any single character. (Will talk about the parenthesis usage at the bottom). Then a single quote. So, basically, this will **match any single char and having a single quote next to it** as shown below.

[image]

As you can see, we have a total of 6 matches. Let us take the 2nd match which is `e"`. Our main intention is to remove the quotes. But, we have matched 2 characters. This is the reason why we have grouped it with parenthesis.

With `Tcl`, we can access 1st subgroup with the help of `\1` and 2nd subgroup with `\2` and so on. Finally, we are substituting the 2 characters with one character which is nothing but the first letter other than quote.  i.e. `e"` is substituted with character `e`.

Notice the use of `-all` flag at the beginning which is responsible for matching all the occurrence of this pattern.

**Note :** `\1` should be used with braces like `{\1}` as I have mentioned. In case, if you want to access it without braces, you have to use `\\1`

Reference : [Non-capturing subpatterns](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml)

Comment: Hi dinesh could you tell me how its matching for six times, then how it getting replaced with that pattern

Comment: @velpandian : I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Dinesh thanks for your quick reply, as you said (.)" will match any one  character then  " should be there. My question is, if you see the end of the input string which is ending with language"" so here it should have 2 matches in this particular area e" and "" but we are getting 1 matches on this area, could you clarify this part .. Thanks

Comment: @velpandian:  After a pattern match, it will move forward to next character and will try to find if it is able to match in the rest of text available.. So, eventually, in the last word, after `e"`, we are left with only one double quote which does not match our criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove *all* quotes and re-add the outer ones. One way:

```
set new [format {"%s"} [string map {{"} {}} $str]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You seek to remove all `"` characters from the string that have at least one character on each side of them. That leads to this regular expression substitution:

```
set transformedString [regsub -all {(.)[""]+(.)} $inputString {\1\2}]
```

The `"` is doubled up and in `[`brackets`]` just to make the highlighting here work. You could use `{(.)"+(.)}` instead.

Comment: Hi donal could you explain the how this substitution works, and kindly let me know any regsub documents, I have basic understanding about regexp