# How to delete a character from the string using TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following string as input

> TCL is "known as "tool command language", TCL is known as "tool
>   command language", TCL is known as "tool command language"...

From the above I want a output like

> TCL is "known as tool command language, TCL is known as tool command
>   language, TCL is known as tool command language"...

could someone help me on this

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Am I traveled back in time Or Is it a Re-post  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538498/how-to-delete-a-character-in-a-string-using-tcl/.  I guess the double quotes moved back in time. :D

Comment: Dinesh this is different from what I asked previously

Comment: @velpandian Please explain how this is different from "only first and last double quotes should be displayed on output, and all other should be deleted"

Comment: @Jerry yes my aim is, in any string first and last double(") quotes should be there apart from all should be removed, that is what am expecting to do

Comment: @velpandian So... it is the same question then?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest technique is a greedy regular expression match/substitute and then a `string map` to fix things up.

```
string map {\u0000 \" \" {}} [regsub {"(.*)"} $sample \u0000\\1\u0000]
```

This *depends* on the fact that you only want the outermost double quotes; it won't work for anything else (not without a much more complex RE). It also depends on the fact that NUL characters (`\u0000`) are vanishingly unlikely in any human-readable piece of text.